# Retrieve number from string most effective way

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering if there is better,more optimal way to retrieve a number from string 
eg.

```
"O5_KK/text1/1239312/006_textrandom"
"O5_KK/text1/1239315/0109_textrandom123"
"O5_KK/text1/1239318/0110_textrandom432"

'O5_KK/text1' - hardcoded, never change.
1239312,1239315,1239318 - random number, unique within row
textrandom,textrandom123,textrandom432 - random string
```

as output I would like to get only numbers:

```
006
0109
0110
```

I know how to do it by using instr,substr,replace function. But it looks terrible to read. I'm looking for other solution, any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: The "most effective way" is of course to store separate information in separate columns.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, you should intercept your data before the database layer and format it so that your numbers are already isolated.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you. Unfortunately I need to base on that string. Gordon proposed me to use regexp_substr. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `regexp_subtr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(val, '/[0-9]+_', 1, 1)
```

And then remove the extra characters:

```
select replace(replace(regexp_substr(val, '/[0-9]+_', 1, 1), '/', ''), '_', '')
```

Comment: I forgot about regexp function... It's quite new. Thanks : )

Comment: If your Oracle version is >= 11.1, you don't need the replace (better to use trim?) - if you use subexpressions, like so: `select regexp_substr(val, '/([0-9]+)_', 1, 1, null, 1)`. The digits portion of the match expression, [0-9]+, is enclosed in parentheses. This is called "subexpression" in Oracle-speak, and is returned if you use the sixth argument to regexp_substr. See Oracle documentation for this use of subexpressions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the part after the third slash before the second underscore:

```
substr(str, instr(str, '/', 1, 3) + 1, instr(str, '_', 1, 2) - instr(str, '/', 1, 3) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number you need is always between the last slash(/) and the last underscore (_), with no characters in between - as in your sample - the best solution uses just substr and instr. Note that regular expressions are slower than straight substr and instr; there are cases when the only solution is regexpr (or regexpr is much easier to write and maintain), but this is not one of those cases.

```
select substr(val, instr(val,'/',-1)+1, instr(val,'_',-1)-instr(val,'/',-1)-1)
```